# Chromedriver does not exist (golang selenium)

Tags: go, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I starting to learn selenium in golang and trying to scrape web page with it but when i run my app i got this error:

`error:exec: "./chromedriver": file does not exist exit status 1`

This is my code snippets :

```golang
 // initialize a Chrome browser instance on port 4444
 service, err := selenium.NewChromeDriverService("./chromedriver", 4444)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("Error:", err)
 }
 defer service.Stop()

 // configure the browser options
 caps := selenium.Capabilities{}
 caps.AddChrome(chrome.Capabilities{Args: []string{
  "--headless-new", // comment out this line for testing
 }})

// create a new remote client with the specified options
 driver, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "")

 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("Error:", err)
 }

 // maximize the current window to avoid responsive rendering
 err = driver.MaximizeWindow("")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("Error:", err)
 }
```

Note that im using windows machine.

I think it works on linux machine, but im really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading driver form [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and moving it in project directory.

You can also add driver to `PATH` for using it in projects.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the project? I don't know for sure if "." is considered as the current folder that you are, or the folder that the project binary is located.

How you're using a windows machine, wouldn't the drive be called "chromedriver.exe"?

Two good pratices that I'd like to suggest is using absolute path instead of relative paths, and using the path library to mount the path, instead of just using strings. Windows in past had problems to fetch paths by using the slash.

https://pkg.go.dev/path

The `Executable()` function could be usefull to get the binary path.

https://pkg.go.dev/os@master#Executable